All points disappear after saving layer. How can I get them back?
I imported a file with many points (5000+) into QGIS and then proceeded to add some more. However, when I click the button "save the changes on layer" all the points disappear. QGIS indicates that there are still over 5000 objects on the layer, I simply can't see them (I also opened the attribute table and it was blank). Any idea how to get them to be visible again? I was also having trouble selecting and deleting points; I was only allowed to add new ones but not to delete or change their places. This applied to both points that were included in the file and new points I added. Also once I close QGIS and open it again, the layer with the points is not available anymore and has been "corrupted", thus rendering the original file useless (I can't even insert it newly into QGIS again, I have to redownload it so it is accepted).

What is the format of your point file? Is it compressed by any chance?

Be aware that many vector file formats can't be edited properly in QGIS. You should onvert the layer to a Geopackage file (or Shapefile, however, this is outdated). Then you should be able to properly edit and save.

@ChloeG it is a KML file I downloaded from Google Earth.
